# Send individual emails to multiple recipients

Tags: python, pandas, email, for-loop, smtplib

I have put together a code to send emails to multiple recipients. However each recipient receives all mails instead of his own.

Dataframe:

`email                  content
 mark@gmail.com         Hi Mark, bla bla
 eve@gmail.com          Hi Eve, bla bla
 john@gmail.com         Hi, John bla bla`

```
for content in df['content']:
    for email in df['email']:
       message = MIMEMultipart()
       message['Subject'] = "Subject"
       message['From'] = 'my email'
       message['Reply-to'] = 'my email'
       message['To'] = '{}'.format(email)

       text = MIMEText(mail)
       message.attach(text)

       server = smtplib.SMTP ('smtp.gmail.com',587)
       server.ehlo()
       server.starttls()
       server.login(login, password) 
       server.sendmail(message['From'], message['To'], message.as_string())
       server.quit()
```

Comment: You are iterating twice. Once over content and once over e-mail. Basically you are sending all possible combinations of content vs email. To do this with a for loop, iterate only once over all rows. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: Thanks @RafaelC!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = {
      'content': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'], 
        'email': ['mail1@mail.com', 'mail2@mail.com', 'mail3@mail.com']
     }

x = 0
for email in df['email']:
        print(email)
        print(df["content"][x]+"\n")
        x+=1
```

Comment: you can make it a bit shorter `df = {'mail1@m.com' : ['text1', 'text2']}`

Answer (score 0):

Just `zip` columns together and omit one loop:

```
for email, content in zip(df['email'], df['content']):
       message = MIMEMultipart()
       message['Subject'] = "Subject"
       message['From'] = 'my email'
       message['Reply-to'] = 'my email'
       message['To'] = '{}'.format(email)

       text = MIMEText(mail)
       message.attach(text)

       server = smtplib.SMTP ('smtp.gmail.com',587)
       server.ehlo()
       server.starttls()
       server.login(login, password) 
       server.sendmail(message['From'], message['To'], message.as_string())
       server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was iterating it twice. Instead of using 2 for loops, the correct way to iterate through out DataFrame is using

Instead of this:

```
for content in df['content']:
    for email in df['email']:
```

Use this:

```
for c in df.itertuples():
   message = MIMEMultipart()
   message['To'] = '{}'.format(c[0])

   text = MIMEText(c[1])
   message.attach(text)
```